# Is there a way to check if a cookie is httponly in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, httponly

Is there a way to check if the cookie is httponly in php?

Comment: For cookies that are *about to be set*, you can query `session_get_cookie_params()`. For cookies that are being set *in the current request*, you can use [`ResponseHeader::get('Cookie')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-HTTP/blob/master/src/ResponseHeader.php#L23) and [`Cookie::parse($cookieHeader)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L287). And, finally, for all cookies that *have already* been set, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. You'll find it in the array returned by [session_get_cookie_params](http://us.php.net/session_get_cookie_params), as long as your PHP is 5.2.0 or newer.

Comment: The OP is reffering to any cookie and your answer seems to be only about session cookie.

Comment: NO!  `session_get_cookie_params()` just gets global values from `php.ini`, not for specific cookie.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that's possible, because this information is not included in the raw headers sent by the browser. In fact, it doesn't make sense to send flags like these back to the server, because they are meaningless to the server and only wastes bandwidth.