# PHP - Check if cookie was set with secure flag

Tags: php, cookies

hopefully this is a straight forward question.

We are moving a site from http to https, the http site has some cookies set that allows a device access to certain areas. I have reworked the code to set the cookie with the secure flag so that it must be returned over HTTPS.

We have a couple of devices out and about that we can physically access but I need to change the cookie on them.

is there a way to check if a cookie has the secure flag set in php. I am hoping to retrieve the cookie check if the flag is set and if not, regenerate the cookie with the secure flag set.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session cookies http & secure flag - how do you set these?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221807/session-cookies-http-secure-flag-how-do-you-set-these)

Comment: Hey thanks but I dont think that answers my questions, I am wanting to know how to check if a secure cookie is set.

Answer (score 0):

**SET Secure Cookie:**
To set secure flag as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040332/7735285) and [PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

```
//php code to create secure cookie.    
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

You are after bool `secure = true` & `httponly=false`

**Read if Cookie is secure:**

and to check if its secure. refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782376/7735285)

> Description
>
> array session_get_cookie_params ( void ) Gets the session cookie
>   parameters.
>
> Return Values
>
> Returns an array with the current session cookie information, the
>   array contains the following items:
>
> "lifetime" - The lifetime of the cookie in seconds. "path" - The path
>
> where information is stored. "domain" - The domain of the cookie.
>
> "secure" - The cookie should only be sent over secure connections.
>
> "httponly" - The cookie can only be accessed through the HTTP protocol.

```
//php code to check if its secure
$CookieInfo = session_get_cookie_params();
var_dump($CookieInfo);
echo $CookieInfo['secure'];
```

This is also a [useful post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101) from other stack if you are after a **single cookie**.

Comment: `session_get_cookie_params()` just gets global values from `php.ini`, not for specific cookie.

Comment: This will not work because it is session related not the cookie.